# Edge Browser Whitelist Webportal | IPP - Iprint is not possible

Tags: url, printing, microsoft-edge, whitelist, group-policy

I am desperate and hope someone can help me.

To restrict access to websites in Edge, the following GPO for whitelist URLs [GPO](https://admx.help/?Category=EdgeChromium&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.Edge::URLAllowlist): is configured.

Via an internal web portal users can add network printers.

The intranet page is druckerauswahl.rhvb.verwalt-berlin.de.

Using Wireshark, I located the following three URLs and stored them in the GPO:

- Iprint.rhvb.verwalt-berlin.de
- Oes4.rhvb.verwalt-berlin.de
- Printer selection.rhvb.verwalt-berlin.de**

These are the settings which in configured inside the gpo:

list of allowed URLs:

```
ipp://iprint.rhvb.verwalt-berlin.de
rhvb.verwalt-berlin.de
iprint:/a
```

here is also a screenshot of the configuration [screenshot gpo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BH11Z.png)

The web portal opens correctly

[Web Portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SUiy.png)

However, when I try to add a printer I get the following error:

[IPP Iprint error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqtvO.png)

when i hover over the link to add a printer i can see the following url in the browser:

```
iprint:/a%20%22ipp://iprint.rhvb.verwalt-berlin.de/ipp/DR0161-SamsungCLP670nd%22
```

Unfortunately I have no idea which URL I have to share for this and I can't see anything in WireShark. I hope someone has an idea.

i tried to encode the string and get the following

```
iprint:/a "ipp://iprint.rhvb.verwalt-berlin.de/ipp/DR0161-SamsungCLP670nd"
```

but even if i whitelist this url i get the same error page

If I whitelist all URL in the GPO using (*) then the printer can be added but then also internet access is possible which should be restricted.

[PoP Adding Printer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tf8Be.png)

I allready tried to identify all urls while a user try to add a printer over the web portal

Comment: Could you please share the values of defined urls in your GPO configuration?

BTW, I don't quite understand what "iprint:/a%20" means, could you please kindly clarify that?
Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi i added some configurations snippets and also added a screenshot of the configuration of the gpo settings. 

the url "iprint:/a%20%22ipp://iprint.rhvb.verwalt-berlin.de/ipp/DR0161-SamsungCLP670nd%22" is i think the browser try to reselvo when adding the printer. I got this url while i hover over the add printer button

Comment: According to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/DeployEdge/edge-learnmmore-url-list-filter%20format#additional-filter-information): **Any other schema is treated as a custom schema, but only the schema:* and schema://* patterns are allowed.** Please try to change the `iprint:/a` to `iprint:*` inside the gpo, and check if the error persists.

Comment: Thank you, it works perfect. This was exactly what I needed. I really appreciate your help, god bless you!

Comment: Glad to know the answer is helpful and the issue was resolved! I have summarized the answer and hope it can help others who have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/DeployEdge/edge-learnmmore-url-list-filter%20format#additional-filter-information): Any other schema is treated as a custom schema, but only the *schema:** and *schema://** patterns are allowed.
Changing the `iprint:/a` to `iprint:*` inside the GPO could solve this issue.